# Acceder a etiqueta HTML desde Java

Tags: java, html, css, spring

Necesito obtener los atributos que tiene una imagen,es decir,esa imagen tiene un serie de elementos HTML en los que tiene el nombre,tags,fecha de creación,etc y necesito obtener el valor de esas etiquetas.

Comment: Hola Stewie. Para poder ayudarte necesitamos mucha mas informacion respecto a tu proyecto. Y sobre todo, lo que has intentado y que errores o dudas concretas has tenido. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Hay librerias especificas para ello, usalas.

Comment: cuales son esas librerias @JDev, no encuentro nada relacionado

Comment: Jsoup por ejemplo.

Comment: Vale,muchas gracias @JDev